# REST API endpoint naming

Tags: node.js, rest, api, url, express

Let's consider that I have this model `Car` :

```
{
   id: id,
   name: name,
   color: color
}
```

and regarding that i have these endpoints that get one car by id:

```
GET http://example.com/api/cars/:id
```

and

```
GET http://example.com/api/cars (get all cars )
```

what is the best practice to name an endpoint that fetch only cars with `color` red  for example.

Comment: This is the best guide I know about designing REST API: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api I would use a queryparam for filtering and I would keep it generic like filter=field&value=value. Also interisting is to place stuff like filtering pagination etc. into the header by using custom-headers.

Answer (score 4):

Why not using a `color` query parameter in the existing `/cars` endpoint?

```
GET http://example.com/api/cars?color=red
```

You are just filtering a collection. That's what query parameters are for.

---

In Express, use `req.query.color` to get the value of the `color` query parameter. For more details, check the [Express API reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Comment: sorry but i tried it, its count as `/api/:cars` which is get one car with id

Comment: @Gintoki It shouldn't count as `/api/:cars`. There may be an issue with your routing.

Comment: what is the problem? you can make http://example.com/api/cars?color=red fetch only cars with color red

Comment: @Gintoki Yes. And you can use `req.query.color` to get the value of the `color` query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all Red color cars use this

```
GET http://example.com/api/cars?color=red
```

For getting specific Red color car use this

```
GET http://example.com/api/cars/{id}?color=red
```

Comment: The second example doesn't make much sense. Why would you apply a filter by color when requesting a single resource by its unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this

get all red cars

```
[GET] http://example.com/api/car?color=red
```

get specific car with red color

```
[GET] http://example.com/api/car?color=red&id=xxx
```

Comment: The second example doesn't make much sense. Why would you apply a filter by color when requesting a single resource by its unique identifier?

Comment: hi, 

i have updated my answer based on your suggestion now. is it sound good?